# static paging vocabulary request

Tags: algorithms, terminology, memory-access

What is the term for an algorithm that always requests the same sequence of pages?  I recall seeing this concept before but haven't been able to find anything on Google without more specific vocabulary.

One algorithm in this category is a linear scan to (say) find the minimum of a set of data. Each page is accessed in order, regardless of the value of previous accesses.

Most algorithms do not fall into this category. For example, a binary search chooses what page to access based on the values in the page before it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the same sequence of pages'? All [page replacement algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm) are suppose to speed up search process not slows it down.

Comment: I mean the algorithm always requests the same pages, in the same order.  As I mentioned a linear scan is an example. By "algorithm" I do not mean a page replacement algorithm, I mean the algorithm generating the page requests

Comment: I don't think that there is any specific name for this case. But question seems to be more about [Adversary models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adversary_model). But decisions of adversary might depend on page replacement algorithm.

Comment: I don't think of an algorithm (for an "application problem") requesting chunks of a level of a memory hierarchy, let alone choose them. Programs and algorithms can conceivably be classified by access pattern(s) on physical or abstract machines. There has been support for cache hinting, page pre-fetch and clever placement on [drum memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drum_memory).

Comment: I believe the concept I was looking for was Data Oblivious algorithms.  (Clearly the description in the question isn't 100% right, but I couldn't remember the details of what I was looking for.)